# Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Core Worker Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, windows-services, backgroundworker

I'm facing some dependency injection issues in .NET Core Worker Service.
Please see the below code in `Program.cs` file.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsof)t", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.File(@"C:\MyApp_Log\Log.txt")
        .CreateLogger();

    try
    {
        Log.Information("Starting up the service.");
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Fatal(ex, "There was a problem starting the service");
        return;
    }
    finally
    {
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }

}
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{

    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseWindowsService()
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {

            services.AddScoped<IMyAppCoreService, MyAppCoreService>();

            services.AddDbContext<MyAppCSContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("Data Source=xx.xxx.xx.xxx;Database=Mydb;User ID = sa;Password=mypassword"));


            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        })
        .UseSerilog();
}
```

And please see below code for `Worker.cs` file

```
private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
private readonly IMyAppCoreService _CoreService;

public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IMyAppCoreService CoreService)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _CoreService = CoreService;
}
public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("The MyApp_CoreService has been Started...");
    return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
}
public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("The MyApp_CoreService has been stopped...");
    return base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
}
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
        _CoreService.CheckAndProcessResult();
        await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

When I run the above query, I got the below query.

Error while validating the service descriptor

> ServiceType: MyApp.CS.Business.Facade.IMyAppCoreService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: MyApp.CS.Business.Services.MyAppCoreService': Unable to resolve service for type 'MyApp.CS.Data.Facade.ICommonRepository' while attempting to activate 'MyApp.CS.Business.Services.MyAppCoreService'.

Can you please tell me where I was done wrong?

**EDIT:** After i register all the interface with its class. then i got new error as follows.

> Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: MyApp_CoreService.Worker': Cannot consume scoped service 'MyApp.CS.Business.Facade.IMyAppCoreService' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'.

Comment: I believe you need to register `ICommonRepository` like `services.AddScoped<ICommonRepository, ClassImplementingICommonRepository>`

Comment: After i posted this content i tried to register ICommonRepository like `services.AddScoped<ICommonRepository, CommonRepository>` . But still having some error. Now it showing. `Cannot consume scoped service 'MyApp.CS.Business.Facade.IMyAppCoreService' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'.`

Comment: Now I register every interface with corresponding class... And the now i got the new error.. `Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: MyApp_CoreService.Worker': Cannot consume scoped service 'MyApp.CS.Business.Facade.IMyAppCoreService' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'.`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You injected the Serivce `IMyAppCoreService` as Scoped. Scoped Services can only be resolved by a `ScopedServiceProvider`.

My first guess is that you didn't mean to - you meant to inject your service as Singleton:

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyAppCoreService, MyAppCoreService>();
```

This however might not work since you are using EF Core which injects its Context-like classes as scoped. You have two options:

1. Have EF Core inject its context class as transient. I would not suggest this as you will be responsible for disposing it. If you want to go through with it, this is how to do it (Startup.cs / Program.cs):

```
services.AddDbContext<YourContext>(opts => { ...config...}, ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

2. Create a scope manually:

Have an `IServiceProvider` property called ServiceProvider injected into `Worker` **instead** of your service.

in ExecuteAsync-Loop:

```
_logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
using (var scope = ServiceProvider.CreateScope())
{
  scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMyAppCoreService>().CheckAndProcessResult();
}
await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
```

This will neatly dispose every Loop's EFCore-Data Context Object and in my opinion is the cleanest option.

Comment: When i write `using (var scope = ServiceProvider.CreateScope())` the `CreateScope` is missing. I am using .net Core 3.1. I have used `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` . Do we need to import some other libraries. ?

Comment: @DileepKumar Make sure to call `CreateScope` on the `ServiceProvider` instance and not the class. The second answer is clearer on this.

Answer (score 6):

Dependency injection:

```
 services.AddScoped<IMyAppCoreService, MyAppCoreService>();

 services.AddDbContext<MyAppCSContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("Data Source=xx.xxx.xx.xxx;Database=Mydb;User ID = sa;Password=mypassword"), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

Worker class:

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public Worker(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMyAppCoreService>().CheckAndProcessResult();
        }

        await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

Source https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task